# Direct assignment to the reverse side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use products.set() instead. Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I get the following error when I POST a new product with a category (the product information is formatted like this:)

```
{
    "product_code": "testcode",
    "name": "testname",
    "quantity": 22,
    "price": 22,
    "categories": [{
        "name": "Test category",
        "products": [],
        "categories": []
}]
}
```

the error

```
Direct assignment to the reverse side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use products.set() instead.
```

and when I use

```
product.categories.set(**category)
```

I get the following error

```
set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

My models.py file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categoriesId = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='categories',on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products')
```

my serializers.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from products_and_categories.models import Product, Category
from django.db import models


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        if 'categories' not in self.fields:
            self.fields['categories'] = CategorySerializer(obj, many=True)      
        return super(CategorySerializer, self).to_representation(obj)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ("name", 'products', 'categories')

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = CategorySerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ("product_code", "name", "quantity", "price", 'categories')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        category_data = validated_data.pop('categories')
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for category in category_data:
            product.categories.create(**category)
        return product
```

Any idea what's going on ?

Comment: Why does your categories data itself contain keys for categories (and products)?

Comment: that's the way it's intended , it's supposed to be a tree like nested structure, the ability to have categories inside of categories .. and products of course .. because it needs to have products.. otherwise  what's the point of the category